# How to access an error object (sent from the backend) properly from an action creator?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, try-catch

I need to access properties of an error object that's being sent from the backend. The error object that I'm getting looks like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "BadRequestError",
        "message": "Error creating record: Phone number must have 11 digits"
    }
}
```

In my action creator, I've always caught errors like the following (focus on the `catch` block):

```
export function myActionCreator(body) {
  const someUrl = `${localhost}/api/product`
  return async dispatch => {
    try{
      const data = await axios.post(someUrl, body)
      // do stuff/dispatch an action with the data as the payload
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error in creating product: ',error)
    }
  }
}
```

With this error object however, no matter if I do `error`/`error.type`/`error.message` or even `error.error`, I can't access those properties from the error object at all. Instead, all I see in the console is:

```
error in creating product:  Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

whereas the actual error object being sent from the backend is the first object above. Can anyone please suggest how should I go about accessing this error object properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the `err` object like this:

```
.catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.message) /*Error creating...*/)
```

Comment: for this error object, looks like I need to do `error.response.data.error.message`. Thanks a lot!